# Vuex: importing a single state from an object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a simple store:

**UsersStore.js**

```
state() {
   return {
       users: {
          name: '',
          userHasPermissions: false,
       }
   }
}
```

I am trying to use `mapState` to have the state accessible in my component.  When I import the entire `User` object of the store like below, it works:

**App.vue**

```
computed: {

    ...mapState('users', {
        myUser: 'user'
    }
```

but I just want to import the `userHasPermissions` state but when I do the following, it does not seem to work:

**App.vue**

```
computed: {

    ...mapState('users', {
        hasPerms: 'user.hasPermissions'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vuex `getters` to get a specific property from any store object

```js
state() {
   return {
       users: {
          name: '',
          userHasPermissions: false,
       }
   }
},
getters: {
  userHasPermission(state) {
    return state.users.userHasPermission || false;
  }
}
```

Now you can use `mapGetters` to map store getters to your vue component

```js
computed: {
  ...mapGetters({
    hasPerms: "userHasPermission"
  })
}
```

If you want to avoid using `mapGetters` and `getters` and use `mapState`, then you need to define a computed function inside your `mapState` to fetch the desired property

```js
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    hasPerms: (state) => state.users.userHasPermission
  })
}
```

Comment: right but it shouldn't need a getter since it's just a Boolean of true/false.  There is no computation done which would make a getter a necessity.

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you check if it works now.
You can use mapState, but you will have to define a computed getter inside your mapState to get the desired property you are looking to map